# How to create U-shaped animation using UView.animate? - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, animation

How can you make U-shape animation in swift using UIView.animate? I'm trying to animate my rounded image to the middle of the `UIView` but I just get the animation that only moves straight. I want it to go down and then up and stop in the middle of UIView.
I tried to use this code:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.7, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: .curveEaseIn, animations: {
   infoImage.center.y += 15
   infoImage.center.x = animationView.frame.size.width / 2
})
```

Screenshot of how animation should look like:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a CAKeyFrameAnimation, which has a path property that will serve as the basis for the animation.  You can use a bezier path to define the U shape.

Here's a simple example of how to animate the entry of a view onto a screen

```
class MyVC {
   var movingView = UIView()
   let endPoint = CGPoint(x: mainView.frame.width * 2/3, y: 200)

   func animateViewEntry() {
      movingView = UIView(frame: CGRect(-100,-100,100,100)) //intially off-screen
      movingView.backgroundColor = .red
      view.addSubview(movingView)
      let animation = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: "position")
      let path = UIBezierPath()
      path.move(to: CGPoint(x:-movingView.frame.width, y:50))
      path.addQuadCurve(to: endPoint,
                        controlPoint:  CGPoint(x:mainView.frame.width * 1/3, y: 350))
      animation.path = path.cgPath
      animation.duration = 2
      animation.fillMode = .forwards
      animation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
      movingView.layer.add(animiation, forKey: "Bounce")
   }
}
```

I'm not happy with how I get the view to stay into its final position at the end of the layer animation as it's not 100% seamless.  I know using the delegate isn't how I've done it previously, but I can't recall how I've previously done it and i don't have the time to play with it right now.  Hopefully someone else will provide an update?

EDITED: updated to remove delegate method and replace with `.fillMode = .forwards` which was what I couldn't think of at the time!

Comment: Thank you! Yes please, if you will have a minute, share some code examples.

Comment: Thanks @JohnSnow for the `.fillMode = .forwards` edit.  That was what had slipped my mind (and for correcting my spelling of animation )